# Any other use for the Starry Night painting in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

In the HoS quest "[Open Sesame](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Open_Sesame!_(Hearts_of_Stone))" for Witcher 3, you can convince the art snob that you're a fellow connoisseur and thereafter bid on a painting by artist "Van Rogh". You can then resell it for profit to a collector in Novigrad.

However, later during the heist you can find a love letter and other documents indicating that Van Rogh was a pseudonym used by

> the Lady Iris von Everec, deceased wife of Olgierd von Everec.

Another painting comes into play later in the questline, but this particular painting only seems useful for resell value despite the connection.

**Is there any other use for the Starry Night painting by Van Rogh?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only other use is to keep it and display it in Corvo Bianco in Blood & Wine.